# Linear Transformation to scalars.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose W is finite dimensional, $T \in L(V, W)$, and $w_1, \dots , w_m$ is a basis of range T. Prove that there exist $\phi_1, \dots \phi_m \in L(V, F)$ such that $Tv = \phi_1(v)w_1 + \dots + \phi_m(v)w_m$ for every $v \in V$. (Where F is the set of real and complex numbers).

What I tried:

Suppose $v_1, \dots v_m$ is a basis of V and that $v \in V$ can be represented by:

$v = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_m v_m$.

$T(v) = T(a_1v_1 + \dots + a_m v_m) = a_1T(v_1) + \dots + a_mT( v_m) = a_1w_1 + \dots + a_mw_m$

We can say this because of the linearity of T.

Therefore $a_1, \dots , a_m = \phi_1(v), \dots, \phi_m(v)$.

Can anyone verify if this is right or if I'm at least on the right track? Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\dim(V)=\dim(Range(T))$, but this isn't true unless nullity(T)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Your try can be made to a proof, but needs some clarifications:

1. $V$ is not said to have the same dimension ($m$) as $W$, it is not even supposed to be finite dimensional.
2. You seem to have implicitly assumed that $T(v_i)=w_i$.

Now, $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ is a basis of the *range* of $T$, as written, so we can find a *preimage* of each $w_i$ in $V$, say $v_i$ (so that $T(v_i)=w_i$).

Use linearity to prove that these $v_i$'s must be independent, then fix a basis in $\ \ker T\,$, which together with the $v_i$'s give a basis of the whole space $V$.

Then the required functions $\phi_i$ are indeed the $i$th coordinate functions w.r.t. this basis.

Comment: So to prove the vi's are linearly independent can I say $T(a_1v_1)+⋯+T(a_mv_m)=a_1w_1+⋯+a_mw_m$ for some pre-images $v_1…v_m$ then $T(a_1v_1 + \dots +a_mv_m) = a_1w_1 + \dots + a_mw_m$.Then the $v_i$ are linearly independent if all $a_i$ are zero when $a_1v_1 + \dots +a_mv_m = 0$ however,$a_1w_1 + \dots a_mw_m = 0$ implies $a_1, \dots a_m = 0$ since it is a basis.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Anyway, we can simply consider the coordinate functions $\psi_i:{\rm ran\,}T\, \to\, F$ w.r.t. $w_1,\dots,w_m$, then define $\phi_i$ as the composite $\psi_i\circ T\,:V\to F$.